# Coevery Create One-to-Many relationship button action

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

In Coevery CMS, I'm trying to create a new child record from a parent record. The parent is related to the child by a One-to-Many Relationship. There is a "New" button but when I click it nothing happens.

The button exists in the Coevery.Relationships--> Views -->RelatedEntityList.cshtml

Here's the code for `RelatedEntityList.cshtml`

```
@using Coevery.Relationship
@using Coevery.Relationship.Records
@using Coevery.Relationship.ViewModels
@{
    var relationships = (IList<RelatedEntityViewModel>)Enumerable.Cast<RelatedEntityViewModel>(Model.Relationships);
}
@foreach (var relationship in relationships) {
    <section class="row-fluid related-list">
        <header>
            <h5>@relationship.Label</h5>
            <div class="btn-toolbar">
                <button class="btn btn-small btn-success"> // <-- No action here 
                    <i class="icon-plus"></i>&nbsp;New
                </button>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div data-ng-controller='RelatedEntityListCtrl' data-ng-init="relationId='@relationship.RelationId';relationType='@relationship.RelationType';entityTypeName='@relationship.RelatedEntityName';viewId=@relationship.ProjectionId;getRelatedData()">
            <div data-ag-grid="gridOptions" data-ag-grid-name="referenceList"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
}
```

I can notice that there is no action for the button but I believe it should open the Create page for the child entity in that relationship. However, I'm not sure how I can fix the code to do that.

The full Coevery code can be found [here](https://github.com/Coevery/Coevery)

Comment: Are there any (angular) console errors?

Comment: @devqon, Thank you for your reply. No there has been no errors. I managed to solve this a while ago, I added the function "add()" for onclick event, this function already exists in Coevery, i'm not sure why it wasn't added to this button. I will post my code as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I added the following code to the button in order to be able to create new child entity from within the parent page:

```
<button class="btn btn-small btn-success" data-ng-controller='RelatedEntityListCtrl' data-ng-click="add()" data-ng-init="relationId='@relationship.RelationId';relationType='@relationship.RelationType';entityTypeName='@relationship.RelatedEntityName';viewId=@relationship.ProjectionId">
    <i class=" icon-plus">
    </i>&nbsp;New
</button>
```